# Setting image duration with -t

Tags: image, ffmpeg

I am generating an ffmpeg command with bash. This is how I'm generating the input list:

```
INPUT_LIST=""
for file in $VIDS_PATH*
do
    if [ ${file: -4} == ".jpg" ]
    then
        INPUT_LIST="${INPUT_LIST} -t $IMAGE_DURATION -i $file"
    else
        INPUT_LIST="${INPUT_LIST} -i $file"
    fi
done
```

And then the filter complex is generated like this:

```
[$i:v]scale=$RES_X:$RES_Y:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=wi   dth=$RES_X:height=$RES_Y:x='if(lt(in_w,in_h),$PADDING,0)':0,setsar=1[v$i];
```

I want images to last for 10 seconds. Now images are only lasting for 1 frame.

The generated input list looks something like this:

```
-i /PATH/World_Map_Perspective_1_4K_preview.mp4 -i /PATH/preview.mp4 -i /root/vids/301img.jpg -t 10
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images have to be looped, so

```
-loop 1 -t 10 -i /root/vids/301img.jpg
```